# Round numbers to next int, hundred and thousand in c#

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I´m triying to round on c# different numbers according to some conditions:

if number is between 0 and 100, round it to nearest integer. Ex: 8.4 = 8, 8.6 = 9
if number is between 101 and 10000, round it to nearest hundred. Ex: 1545 = 1500, 1551 = 1600

if number is > than 10000, round it to neares thousand . Ex: 15499 = 15000, 15600 = 16000.

But I´ve tried using math.round and It doesn´t seems to work. Could you please give me a hint?

thank you

Comment: What exactly doesn't seems to work?

Comment: Show what you've tried with `Math.Round`.  Have you tried an 'if` or `switch` block?

Comment: `Math.Round()` is used for decimal numbers, aka numbers with decimal places, not integers. You'll have to write your own version.

Comment: What happens for negative numbers?

Comment: Can´t use an if or switch block because these conditions are from a table in a database, so they could be modified.

Comment: instead of looking for a quick answer which you may or may not understand based on what you are looking for .. you could easily accomplish this using a combination of a `switch()case{}` statement along with some conditional check this can be done ..however not showing what you have tried as well as not putting in any effort on your part will probably `yield` in mega `downvotes and or closing`

Comment: Why? You don't have to hard-code the decimal places. What have you tried? Where is the code?

Comment: You don't need a switch statement, you can use Math.Log10 to find the appropriate multipliers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code will do the job.

```
double number = 1551;
if (number >= 0 && number <= 100)
{
    number = Math.Round(number);
}
else if (number > 100 && number <= 10000)
{
    number = Math.Round(number / 100) * 100;
}
else if (number > 10000)
{
    number = Math.Round(number / 1000) * 1000;
}

Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Anyway I advice you to not hardcode these values but think of another logic that is more easy to be abstracted.

Comment: This isn't a hint as much as you doing someone's homework for them.

Comment: Well I am trying to help. He may learn something of this. :)

Comment: @NikolayKostov, as I recall, the idea is to answer questions, not to provide hints.

Comment: Thank you I was wrong using % division.

Comment: @NikolayKostov If this is coursework, the OP will not get top marks and probably fail. This can be solved with a single line if he thinks how to get the required multipliers. The switch statement is the trap most other students will fall in